# How to auto-hyphenate a pages document that uses two languages?

Tags: pages, language

So I have a document in pages that uses English and Greek (both are used interchangeably, in that some paragraphs are Greek, some are English).

When I enable hyphenation, it hyphenates only the English parts in my document. Then I switched my system settings to have Greek as the primary language, which caused pages to hyphenate the Greek text in my document, but not the English. How can I have both be auto-hyphenated at the same time?

Is there an easy solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to use a more advanced word processor like Word or maybe LibreOffice for this.  Pages can't tag pieces of text by language.